# Web API call times out from Azure App Service X

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, azure-api-management

We have an Azure App Service running the latest version of .Net 6. When this app service receives a request, it will do a request (using httpclient) to another API that is accessed through Azure API Management. Our app has a constant traffic, sometimes it is heavy loaded and sometime the load is less, but it does have traffic flowing always. We are receiving timeouts randomly on some of the requests made to APIM and we see that after a while or in few seconds, retry works. Also, not all calls are timing out.

From the logs, We also see the requests reaching to backend or to the last layer of services at after 120 seconds. However, we do not want to increase the timeout at App Service X (i.e. second layer). Since http client times out after 100 seconds, our App Service X request times out after 100 seconds.

Also, after 120 seconds, we see sometimes multiple requests are sent to backend service i.e. last layer.

[image]

Below is the error log we are seeing:

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)

We checked following things:

1. we are using asynchronous execution. Using await with asynchronous methods to avoid blocking the thread and improve responsiveness.
2. We are using typed clients pattern for http request.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#typed-clients
3. We cannot set custom Timeout for Specific Operations since we are dependent on multiple services. It may be possible that sometimes the timeout is genuine as one of the service is not responding.

Comment: are there any APIM policies setup in the second APIM instance sunch as rate limiting or validating jwt token etc?

Comment: is your API Management running on Serverless tier?

Comment: @RimazMohommed - I know APIM returns 429 when reaching rate limit if you have it set. Though, we don't have it set on the 2nd APIM instance.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - API Management is on premium tier which is not serverless. thanks!

Comment: This sounds like the default `HttpClient` timeout of 100 seconds. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-8.0

Comment: Additionally, what type of call are you handling? If it's something where the client doesn't need an immediate response (e.g. a `POST` without a return object) then it might be better to consider putting the data into a queue or bus immediately after "App Service X". This would let App Service X close the HTTP connection much more quickly. As well as a benefit to the timeout problem, it would also help with scalability because you're less likely to exhaust the pool of available sockets.

Comment: Also, a separate note on async. Just because you're using `async`, don't forget that it will still be keeping the same socket open for the duration of that call. `async` just lets the CPU go off and do something else; it doesn't release the HTTP socket. You're still tying it up for 100 seconds or more, even if it's awaiting async processes inbetween. Although to offer more relevant suggestions, people will probably need to see some of your App Service X code.

Comment: @AndrewB - thank you for responding. all these are Get/Post/Put, where client is waiting for the response object.  Just to provide more info, 95% of the calls are usually in milliseconds. while 5% can ends up in seconds. Also, to note, we observe that calls are reaching to Second app service after 120 seconds odd. However, at 100 seconds, App Service X has already responded to the client with 500 timeout. Question is what makes request reach  the second app service after 20 seconds when the request that was initiated has already been closed before 20 seconds.

Comment: @AndrewB I will add some part of code specific to http request in some time. thanks!

Comment: Yes I'd suggest you show people the actual code of the "App Service X". I wonder if this will help people suggest some tactics, such as not waiting indefinitely on outgoing HTTP calls if you think those services are problematic. So yes - share the relevant code blocks perhaps.